# App storeに審査を出さないでiOSアプリをダウンロードする方法（testflight以外で）webダウンロードのため、untrustedの状態になるのは問題ありません。

Tags: ios, app-store, apple

App Store掲載申請しているアプリがありますがなかなか審査が通りません。
そのため、別の手段として、弊社のwebサイトから、アプリをダウンロードして頂くような形式を考えております。

時々そういった形式で配布しているアプリがありますが、それらがどういうふうに配布しているのかがわからず困っております。

少なくともtestflightやdeploygateのように専用アプリをダウンロードする必要がないのが特徴です。

ただ、そのかわり、ダウンロード後に、ユーザー側で、Settingsから該当アプリの承認をして頂く必要があります。

該当しそうなワードで検索しているのですが、配布方法について言及されている記事が見当たらず、そのような記事をご存知でしたらいただきたいです。

※ また、Apple Developer Enterprise Program を用いると、同様のことができますが、
100件までしかダウンロードできない制約があり、制約がない、もしくは、制約があっても1000件、1万件はインストールできるような方法を確立したいと考えております。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 広く回答を募るためこちらにも投稿させていただいております。
https://teratail.com/questions/141575?nli=5b755e8d-a4a0-4e1a-a480-7f290a180009#reply-213988

Comment: Apple Developer Enterprise Programは社内配布向けなので、不特定多数に配布するのはルール違反ですよ。。。

Answer (score 8):

不特定多数に向けて、AppStoreを介さずにiOSアプリを配布する手段はありません。
技術的には可能ですが、認められていません。

AppStoreを介さずに「特定」多数にアプリを配布する方法としてEnterprise Programがあります。これは１つの組織内であれば、登録デバイス数の制限を受けることなくアプリの配布が可能です。

１つの組織を超えて、しかし特定の利用者向けに配布したい場合、Volume Purchaseを利用します。B2Bのアプリなどがこれに当たります。業務アプリを開発していくつかの企業に導入する、などを想定したものです。

いずれにしても、一般の不特定多数のユーザー向けに使えるソリューションではありません。
仮にそれができるなら、みんなそれを使っているであろうということからもわかると思います。